# ASP .NET Master Pages with Bootstrap and fixed footer, page content clashes with footer

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, footer

Following is my ASP .NET Master page. Bootstrap.min.cs is present in my theme and the theme is defined in my webconfig file.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeFile="HomePage.master.cs" Inherits="HomePage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>e-Recruitment</title>
</head>
<body style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .center {
            overflow: auto;
        }

        footer {
            position: fixed;
            height: 50px;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .borderless td, .borderless th {
            border: none;
        }

        .checkboxlist-inline li, .radiobuttonlist-inline li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .checkboxlist-inline, .radiobuttonlist-inline {
            margin-left: 8px;
        }

            .checkboxlist-inline label, .radiobuttonlist-inline label {
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 8px;
            }
    </style>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <form id="MainForm" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Company" Name="Company.JavaScript.CompanyScript.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdPanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="ParentDiv" class="container-fluid center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <img src="../Content/Images/logonew.png" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-11">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageContent" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <footer class="footer fixed-bottom">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 10%">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblTheme" runat="server" Text="Site Theme"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 20%; text-align: left">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTheme" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTheme_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 70%; text-align: right">
                                <small><i>&copy;<asp:Label ID="lblComp" runat="server" Text=" Company 2018"></asp:Label>
                                    &reg;<asp:Label ID="lblRights" runat="server" Text=" Some message"></asp:Label></i></small>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </footer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine, Footer stays at the bottom and pages work perfectly, but only problem is when the page content increases it is clashing with the footer, I have a save button in one of my child pages at the extreme bottom of the page, it is getting hiiden by my footer, User is able to view the button but unable to click because it is behing my footer, how to avoid this page content clashing into the footer.

Comment: you are setting footer to `fixed` and position as `0`. Provide `50px` padding / margin to content

Comment: Hey, thank you sooo much it worked. Please post it as an answer.